# Problem, how to store dynamic data?

Tags: objective-c

I am building an application in which i am getting data from xml and data can grow dynamic,i am displaying location name on first view, and each location have multisubviews and sub views have multi hotels name, hotel image and hotel description and each hotel has further photo gallery, so at this condition i am facing problem how to store data on array i mean what will be smart logic to handle this and arrays should use as minimus as possible, Someone can help me???

Comment: The question should be more specific. Regarding your description I can suggest to use CoreData, not a hand-managed data tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data has a good size learning curve, but a lot of boiler plate code is provided for you and the Apple documentation is pretty good. It's definitely worth learning, especially for things like this. For a starter, so you will understand it in perspective, your hotel will be your entity.